# When accessing all pages except the homepage I get Nothing Found

Tags: permalinks

I try to identify the reason why when visiting any page I get the message

Nothing Found
Ready to publish your first post? `<a href="http://site.local/wp-admin/post-new.php">Get started here</a>.`

[image]

For this instance of wordpress I configured and enabled the following virtual host

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/site.local.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName site.local
     ServerAlias www.site.local
     ServerAdmin user.name@domain.com

     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress-workspace/site
     <Directory /var/www/html/wordpress-workspace/site>
         AllowOverride All
         Order Allow,Deny
         Allow from All
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site.local.error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site.local.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The content of the `.htaccess` file is as follows

```
#BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

#END WordPress
```

Links are items created in the menu settings

Could you give me a hint on how to solve this behavior?

If you need other information please let me know.

Greetings and thanks in advance

**Update**

I include view with current permalink configuration

[image]

Comment: Is the rewrite module active? Have you saved the permalinks in your site's Admin pages (Settings -> Permalinks)?

Comment: Thanks for comment. rewrite is enabled. When trying `sudo a2enmod rewrite` I get `Module rewrite already enabled`

Comment: About permalinks I updated the question to include the view with current permalink configuration

Comment: Have you checked your site's error logs?